# Javascript-код, установка и возвращение сookie

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, друзья! У меня почему-то не работает довольно простой пример работы с cookies-переменными. Вот код:

```
 <button class="but1" name="button1" onclick="save_cookie();">Присвоить куки-переменную</button><br/>
 <button class="but2" name="button2" onclick="write_cookie();">Вернуть куки-переменную</button><br/>
 <button class="but3" name="button3" onclick="alert(document.cookie);">Вывести все куки-переменные</button><br/>
 <div id="div1">Тут будет вывод переменной example</div>

<script language='JavaScript'>
  function set_cookie(name, value, expires)
  {
    if (!expires)
    {
      expires = new Date();
    }
      document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString() +  "; path=/";
  }

  function save_cookie() 
  {
    var name = "example" // имя cookie
    var tmp = "Привет, я ваша cookie!"; // записываемое значение
    expires = new Date(); // получаем текущую дату
    expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (1000 * 86400 * 365)); //срок хранения
    set_cookie(name, tmp, expires); // устанавливаем cookie в set_cookie
  }

  function get_cookie(name)
  {
    cookie_name = name + "=";
    cookie_length = document.cookie.length;
    cookie_begin = 0;
    while (cookie_begin < cookie_length)
    {
      value_begin = cookie_begin + cookie_name.length;
      if (document.cookie.substring(cookie_begin, value_begin) == cookie_name)
      {
         var value_end = document.cookie.indexOf (";", value_begin);
         if (value_end == -1)
         {
           value_end = cookie_length;
         }
           return unescape(document.cookie.substring(value_begin, value_end));
      }
      cookie_begin = document.cookie.indexOf(" ", cookie_begin) + 1;
      if (cookie_begin == 0)
      {
        break;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  function write_cookie() 
  {
     // получаем cookie и записываем значение в div с помощью innerHTML
     document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = get_cookie('example'); 
  }
```

Так вот по нажатию первой кнопки идет установка переменной. Второй кнопкой я в div с именем div1 вывожу переменную эту, но она не выводится почему-то. И последняя, третья кнопка, выводит все куки-переменные. Это тоже почему-то не работает, ни одной переменной куков на локальном компьютере не находит. В чем может быть проблема подскажите?

Comment: У меня всё работает и выводится. Может в оригинальном коде вы также, как здесь, не закрыли <script>? Или же вы тестируете на локалхосте?

Comment: я не на веб-сервере проверяю страницу, а просто запускаю этот html-файл и пробую чтобы он работал. Или надо обязательно на веб-сервер кидать его (к примеру на localhost)? Это же скрипт-javascript и html один, я думал он может работать в любом месте.

Comment: Обязательно, чтоб он был на каком-то адресе не file://

Comment: Куки привязаны к домену, минимум к локалхосту.